# Can an airline operate a flight on the same route with the same flight number twice in one day?

Tags: air-travel, factoids

Can an airline operate with two flights in one day to the same destination with the same flight number
for example

DUBAI to MUSCAT ETD 0400Z SSV 221

and

DUBAI MUSCAT ETD 1300Z SSV 221

Comment: What airline is this?

Comment: Are you sure these are for the same day? I've seen lots of cases where eg `Airline Flight 123` leaves at 8am on some days, and 2pm others, that's quite normal

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/is-a-flight-number-unique-for-the-schedule-origin-and-destination

Comment: What is the flight number?

Comment: These are not the same flights.  221 is not a flight number.  Etihad between Dubai and Muscat operates 3 flights 382, 384, 388.  http://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=OMAA&destination=OOMS.  But if the flight is delayed it can turn out that same flight on the same day leaves at 2 different times.  See April 8: http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ETD221

Comment: @Karlson that's probably good enough for an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can two different planes share the same flight number?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/can-two-different-planes-share-the-same-flight-number)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that question. That question was asking if the same flight number could be on a different aircraft on different days of the week (to which the answer is "Yes, and it often or usually is.")

Answer (score 5):

These are not the same flights.

221 is not a flight number. Etihad between Dubai and Muscat operates [3 flights 382, 384, 388](http://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=OMAA&destination=OOMS). But if the flight is delayed it can turn out that same flight on the same day leaves at 2 different times. See April 8: [flightaware.com/live/flight/ETD221](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ETD221)

Comment: +1 Good catch! I am wondering what SSV 221 means, now…

Comment: The flight doesn't actually have to be delayed to leave at different times on different days. Many flights are actually scheduled that way (where they leave at one time on certain days of the week and another time on other days of the week.) Here's a current example from [Cathay Pacific](http://i.imgur.com/iHYX4oM.png). CX920 leaves at 12:25 pm Tues, Wed, Thurs, and Sat and 8:05 pm Fri, Sun, Mon.

Comment: @reirab The issue is the same flight number leaving to the same destination at different times on the same day.

Comment: @Karlson Ah, right. Sorry, I misread your answer.

Comment: A very long time ago, but thought it worth remarking that SSV is probably a codeshare with ETD. SSV is (or was, at least) the 3 character ICAO for the now-defunct "Skyservice Airlines Inc.": https://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/reference/codes/aircarrier/ac2.txt and https://www.avdelphi.com/airline.html?id=8404 have more details.

Answer (score 4):

I think according to IATA standard no flights should operative using the same flight number on the same day.
If the flight is delayed by a day, the flight number should be changed by adding a suffix D like XX1234 to XX1234D.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. BTW, did you have a chance to see it written formally somewhere? I'd be interested in a link.